# Show Opportunity Fields History for users with no Opportunity object access

Tags: visualforce-component, field-history, opportunity-history

We redesigned our org recently to move away from CRM standard objects (e.g. Opportunity, Product) in order to utilize a cheaper force.com licenses. But one of the issues was an inability to migrate the fields history (and it's also not possible to load the old history records into a new standard History object for new custom object to where Opportunities were moved)
So, I'm wondering what possible solutions are. After some researches I've discovered the following:

1. Create a custom object to load old history records (Counts as custom object (basic force.com license has limit of 10), data duplication, have to keep this, and also a standard History for new history records)
2. Create (or reuse [one](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F000000095wwIAA) or [two](http://www.iterativelogic.com/create-your-own-history-related-list-in-visualforce/) ) a custom component that could query an old History object records (I hope that when I'll use `without sharing` aka system mode it would allow to access those records)
3. Make a use of standard 'Go to list' functionality when SF displays all history records by this link `/_ui/common/history/ui/EntityHistoryFilterPage?id=`(I prefer this, but it respects a user security, including fields access, so users with no access to the old Opportunity object get 'insufficient privileges' error)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: we did #1 and #2 in our org for a similar use case (preserving field history from an org Foo merged into org Bar)

Answer (score 2):

From what i understand from OP is that you know the above solution and looking for any other possible solution.

We have faced this problem and here is what we did.

Instead of creating custom object for storing history we used External object.

This external object was stored on heroku postgrace DB.

Then we have inline VF page that query from heroku DB + History table and show it on Opp object.

This approach have following advantage.
1) You can save one custom object for some other use
2) data storage will on SF will be less
3) You can store some other data as well on heroku if needed

Disadvantage:
1) You will need to buy heroku licence. Its very cheap($50/month) compare to sfdc data cost